# Is there any way to set elevation color in the RaisedButton widget?

Tags: flutter

Here is an example:

```
RaisedButton(
 shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
 ),
 padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
 elevation: 5, //Here is the elevation size
 onPressed: onPressed,
),
```

I guess it should work with this wrap [ElevatedButtonThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButtonThemeData-class.html), but it doesn't work

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
      style: ButtonStyle(
        shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
          Colors.red, //Here
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

How to solve this?

Comment: This has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230640/how-to-set-a-custom-elevation-color-on-flutter#:~:text=It%20is%20not%20possible%20to,the%20BoxShadow%20however%20you%20want.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set a custom elevation color on Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57230640/how-to-set-a-custom-elevation-color-on-flutter)

Comment: @VirajD sorry, but no. It doesn't fit me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You should use `ElevatedButton` instead of `RaisedButton`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          style: ButtonStyle(
            elevation: MaterialStateProperty.all<double>(5),
            shadowColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.pink),
          ),
          child: Text('CLICK ME'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```